# How to calculate ETH percentage supply in profit?

Tags: ether, mysql, totalsupply, dune

I'm trying to calculate the ETH percentage supply in profit.
Definition is: The percentage of circulating supply in profit, i.e. the percentage of existing coins whose price at the time they last moved was lower than the current price.

As I read the documents of ETH, ETH uses the account-based model, while BTC uses UTXO model.
My idea is to get the amount of token at the time they last moved (transfer/burn/mint?) and compare to the current price.

So which database from dune analytics can I use the obtain the needed data?

Thank you in advance!